# How to check modified form fields in Server side

Tags: java, jsp

I am having a form with 700 fields. Suppose if an user updates one or two fields, i want to update that particular fields in Database. My question is how to find that particular(modified) fields in server side, i dont want to execute update query to all the tables. I am using Jboss server, Java, Jsp & MySql

Comment: You could execute the select query then to compare the changed fields

Comment: You can use clientside JS to mark changed fields as soon as the user edits them. Then the request will tell you what has changed. Without JS you need to compare the values before and after the form submit. Maybe save them in the session to save DB requests. - or setup proper DB caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic approach:

First don't give `name` attribute to the fields initially. Now when user edits the fields, using javascript give the `name` attribute to the field. That is it !  On the server side you will always receive data in name=value pair, if there is no `name` the browser won't pass the field value to the server.

**EDIT:**

Keep hidden fields with the old values but with no names. This will help you to test whether user has entered new value or not.

This is an example:

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('input', '.to-edit', function(e) {
        var box = $(this);
        var prv = box.prev().val();
        var cur = box.val();
        if ('' === cur || prv === cur) {
            box.prop('name', '');
        } else {
            box.prop('name', 'txtName');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: how do you know the user gives a new value . what happens if he enters the same value and submit it again ?

Comment: But however he has to send the objects from the server-side before loading this page

Comment: @sankrish, there is no magic behind this, either way we have to put efforts on it, OP has asked: `how to find that particular(modified) fields in server side, i dont want to execute update query to all the tables`, so anyways I am suggesting the client side efforts to avoid to server side efforts.